# How to disable phone calls and text messages in iOS / on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers, call

I don‘t use mobile phone call and text messaging any longer but I need to keep cellular data / internet running since FaceTime, WhatsApp replace sms and cellular calls with better quality.

To implement that strategy I currently use a secondary sim card from my father. The upside is that it’s entirely free, the downside is that I get his phone calls, too. I plan to move to an individual solution some time in the future, this setting was to test whether or not pure-internet communication mode would be feasible.

Is there any way you are aware of to entirely and cleanly switch off the phone and text-message functions of the iPhone without affecting any other functions?

Answer (score 1):

Some carrier can provide sim card that cellular data only.
Mainly used  for iPad notebook and IoT device .
You can use it for your iPhone to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iPhone as an Internet connected device SIM free, i.e. without any SIM card into the device. You'll only need a SIM card plugged in when activating the device after a reset.

Another option would be to turn on Airplane mode which will turn off the cellular functionality. Wi-Fi and Bluetooth can be turned on while Airplane mode is active. More details can be found in the Apple Support article, [Use Airplane Mode on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204234).